# Definitions of UInt8, UInt16, UInt32

Tags: swift

Can anyone tell me what the difference’s between UInt8, UInt16, UInt32 are?

I don’t understand it that well.

I need to understand it when sending data to a Bluetooth device.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add some context: for example, a sample of the code which sends data to a Bluetooth device. It could be important for the explanation.

Comment: Define 'it' in "I don’t understand it that well."

Comment: `UInt8` == 8 bit == 1 byte,  `UInt16` == 16 bit == 2 byte,  `UInt32` == 32 bit == 4 byte.

Comment: And why do you not ask about UInt64 ?  (see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/numbers_and_basic_values/special-use_numeric_types ) or do you understand that well ?

Comment: U means unsigned. Int means integer. 8, 16, 34 or 64 means the number of bits. The more bits the more combinations of zero and ones. For 8-bits (2^8) you can have a total of 256  combinations of 0 and 1, 1 byte UInt8 with a range of `0...255`, 00000000, 00000001, 00000010, 00000011, and so on .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UInt8 is a unsigned integer = a byte consisting of 8 Bits without sign (positive value from 0..255)

UInt16 is 16 bits long = only positive values from 0..65535
UInt32 is 32 bits long value

Details see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types